# Playing MIDI in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, quicktime, firefox, plugins, midi

Playing midi files in either Chrome or Firefox used to be easy: it just worked by invoking Quicktime. However, Quicktime stopped supporting midi after version 7.6.6. After upgrading, the same websites that used to work now fail.

I installed the old version (so I have two versions of Quicktime installed), and I can now play midi files locally on my computer.

However, I can't figure out how to get either (or both!) Firefox or Chrome to use Quicktime 7.6.6 as a plugin. Does anyone know of a way to do that?

NOTE: I don't care if it is Quicktime that is playing the midi or some other plugin, but I don't know of any other plugin that plays midi. If you know of any way to get midi to play, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: see this post: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/115784/14994